# How to programmatically add event based on a variable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I'd like to programmatically add an event, e.g. `@click` depending if on another variable. I can't really use a ref to do something like `this.$refs.example.addEventListner("click", someFunction)` because I'm doing it for a `v-for`

I've tried doing something like `@click="clickable ? clicked : null"` but the function isn't bound even when `clickable` is true

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="main" @click="clickable ? clicked : null">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      clickable: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/m941978v9x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `()` would allow it to be executed.

```
@click="clickable ? clicked() : null"
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/p9l4ozx60x

---

For more complex conditional statements, you could filter the method using computed.

Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/wnv6kjq2wk

```
<div class="main" @click="clickedMaybe">
</div>
```

and

```
  computed:{
    clickedMaybe(){
      if(this.clickable) return this.clicked;
      return function(){};
    }
  },
```

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't think you'd need to use `()` to make it executable since the default `@click` allows you to pass a function without it. Will mark when can

Comment: I think Vue will automatically detect whether what's provided is a method name or a Javascript statement. `clickable ? clicked : null` is a statement. I think that Vue's too magical sometimes that it causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, You can conditionally render the DOM node, I tried it and it's working like charm.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <div class="main" v-if="clickable" @click="clicked"></div>
    <div class="main" v-if="!clickable"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      clickable: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: works nice when it's simply just got 1 props, but I've got like 10 props and events on it, so making a secondary node just to enable 1 event is too much bloat.

Comment: @A.Lau Right. but try consol log this in both the cases.